# Supporting Ajax on my Galaxy ACE

Tags: browser

I have a galaxy ace s5830, and a website that heavily uses jquery and ajax calls. The problem is my mobile does not support ajax.

Is there something that can be done with the mobile (probably install something such as a browser or a plugin) or if not then how to I change my website to run on my mobile

Comment: How do you open the site now? You should already be using some kind of a browser app in order to do that.

Comment: i have used the default browser and uc mobile

Comment: but both of 'em don't support ajax and the only browsers that do don't work on my mobile

Comment: That sounds strange to me, because XMLHttpRequest (which is the foundation for AJAX) has been around for decades, and even the most primitive browsers support it. I would suggest to try simple testing pages that create XHR requests (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) to see whether it works or not.

Comment: I am using jquery ajax with json reply, maybe that's the problem. I have not tried XMLhttp as I am not that comfortable with XML but I will try it soon and reply